# Google Maps Data

Tags: data, google-maps

Is it possible to obtain a dataset of all search results in a google maps search? For example: if I want a list of all gas stations in Chicago, complete with addresses, store name, latitude-longitude coordinates etc.

Is such a data set against Google user agreement terms? I only plan on using the data for academic research questions.

Comment: I don't know anything about Google's terms for this kind of thing, but I highly doubt you could acquire data from them in this manner.  Here is their customer service #, good luck with that.  (650) 253-0000

Comment: if you are specifically looking for that gas station data, the IL DNR (as well as MI, WI, possibly others) keep a database of all underground storage tanks with the attribute data you mentioned above.

Comment: A place to consider posting for any data questions is the [opendata.se] (Beta) Stack Exchange.

Comment: @cl3 DNR is a great suggestion, I will check it out. Thanks!